# Basic Templates C++

Tags: c++, templates, generics

While reading about templates I encountered the following code:

```
template<class T>
void f(T x, T y) {
cout << "template" <<endl;
}

void f(int w, int z) {
cout << "Non template" <<endl;
}

int main() {
f(1,2);
f('a','b');
f(1,'b');
}
```

The book states that the output for this code would be:

> ```
> Non template
>
> Template
>
> Non template
> ```

The last line, f(1,'b'), is baffling me (or its output rather). What is the rule of thumb that the compiler is following in this instance? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there some confusion here over how C++ prefers *specialized* implementations over generic template ones?

Comment: @tadman No. That isn't what confused me. As MichaelCMS stated in their answer, the *implicit casting* part was the vague concept here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First function :

You have a f(int,int) defined, so compiler will take that one.
If you want to explicitly use the template you can call it like :

```
 f<int>(1,2);
```

Second function :

Well, you don't have a f(char,char) defined, but it matches your template definition, so it uses that.

Third function :

You don't have a template for f(T1, T2) . However you have an implicit cast to int from char on a function that will take f(int,int). So it takes the function again.

Furthermore if f(int,int) wouldn't be defined, then your Template function wouldn't qualify to be called for f(int,char) since it has different types as parameters.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. It confused me because it was a *char*. And *char* to *int* casting is counter-intuitive. I guess if it was a *double*, perhaps I wouldn't have gotten confused.

Comment: With `f(1,'b')`, both the template and the non-template can be called. And each will require exactly one conversion. So why does the non-template win?

Comment: @AaronMcDaid On my compiler(s) the template cannot be called when you have (int,char) args, because it doesn't match the template signature ... I don't know how you managed to call the template on your code. Regarding the non-template win, think about the (int,int) example. If the template would expand, it will create a function f(int,int). However, such function already exists and it's user defined. It makes sense for the compiler to use the user defined function instead of overwriting it.

Comment: @MichaelCMS, I've tested in on  http://ideone.com/06wHmk . I just added another call to `f(1,'b')``, so that all all four combinations of `int` and `char` are covered. Are you saying this shouldn't work?

Comment: @Aaron McDaid Comment you f (int,int) . You should get undefined symbol errors since the template doesn't cover (int,char) or (char,int)

Comment: Sorry, I was thinking of something else last night. I shouldn't be on StackOverflow in the morning before my coffee :-P  Anyway, so a template where the same parameter type appears twice (`T`) will only if the two parameters really have exactly the same type?

Comment: Yes. If you want to allow different parameters you need to have T1 and T2.

Answer (score 1):

The template takes both arguments of the same type `T`.

`f(1,'b')` doesn't match the template because `1` and `'b'` are not of the same type.